# Why is the second instrution evaluated before the first one?

Tags: lua, evaluation

I was doing some calculations to use as the testcases for a question I'm going to post on PCCG Stack Exchange, and I noticed that in a piece of code like this:

```
for i = 0, 20 do
    io.write(i..": ")
    diff(i)
end
```

(where `diff` is a function which does some pretty heavy calculation and prints the result), the result of `diff` is first calculated and, only then, `i:` and the result of `diff` are printed.

But why is this happening? Shouldn't I see `i:` before and during the calculation, and the result of the calculation only after? Why is it waiting for `diff` to execute before?

I first noticed this using Luajit, but it also happens on vanilla Lua and even outside of a `for` loop.

Comment: this typically happens because the output is buffered, in java you would see a difference if you would write to the error stream, but i don't know how it's in lua.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as with many other output functions in many other languages, `io.write` output is buffered. It is evaluated, it is just your output is now in intermediate buffer pending flushing or filling of this buffer. Add an `io.flush()` call if you need your data to go through right now.

Comment: So does `print` automatically flush the output? I don't need to display the number, I was just curios about this.

Comment: @user6245072 - Lines non-terminated with LF are buffered.  `print` always appends LF to the end of string, so its output is immediate.